# Get a value from JS in WebBrowser with C#

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8, browser

I meet a strange behavior. I dont understand my mistake.
I want to read a value from an HTML page. I can obtain it with :

**JavaScript**

```
function getSize() {
    return (size.toString());
}

getSize();
```

Output (in Chrome console)

```
120
```

**C#**

```
// wBrowser is not null and the page is loaded
String o = wBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "getSize();").ToString();
Debug.WriteLine(o);
```

Here `o` is empty.

I read the [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/be9zzz62%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and try some research without success. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: You can try to call it like this: `wBrowser.InvokeScript("getSize").ToString();'` or `wBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "size;").ToString();'`.

Comment: @LukaszM I already try `getSize()` alone without eval. I will try your two solutions. Why not post this comment as an answer ?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure it solves Your issue first :). I'm glad You've found the solution :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ...

Just found my error.
My solution is working. Lukasz's solutions works too.

I just forgot to swith the run mode from `Release` to `Debug` ...

So working solutions are :

```
String o1 = wBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "getSize();").ToString();

// Lukasz's 1st solution
String o2 = wBrowser.InvokeScript("getSize").ToString();

// Lukasz's 2nd solution
String o3 = wBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "size.toString();").ToString();
```

Both print the right size.

Maybe it could be helpful for someone else ...